# how to ignore elements not in the XSD schema while parsing

Tags: java, xml, validation, parsing, xsd

I have a requirement in java to parse XML and skipping any tag not defined in the XSD schema. in other words only elements in Schema are parsed other elements are ignored without through a validation error.
Validation error will exists only if the element found in the XSD is of different data type ...etc

** very simple schema:-**
 root contains x,y,z all strings.

example 1

```
<root>
    <x>anyvalue</x>
    <y>anyvalue</y>
    <z>anyvalue</z>
</root>
```

result 1

```
<root>
    <x>anyvalue</x>
    <y>anyvalue</y>
    <z>anyvalue</z>
</root>
```

example 2:-

```
<root>
    <x>anyvalue</x>
    <notdefined>anyvalue</notdefined>
    <z>anyvalue</z>
</root>
```

result 2:-

```
<root>
    <x>anyvalue</x>
    <z>anyvalue</z>
</root>
```

example 3:-

```
<root>
    <notdefined>anyvalue</notdefined>
    <x>anyvalue</x>
    <z>anyvalue</z>
</root>
```

result 3:-

```
<root>
    <x>anyvalue</x>
    <z>anyvalue</z>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing the schema, use wildcards with processContents="skip" or processContent="lax" to ensure that undeclared elements do not produce a validity error.

If you are working from a pre-existing schema, then either check whether your parser / validator allows you to filter the errors you see or else derive a secondary schema from the pre-existing one.  Use wildcards to make things valid in your secondary schema even if they are not valid in the primary schema.

Comment: Could you present an example of xsd that covers the exact case of the question? I can't seem to find a proper example with wildcards and processContents